# Capture Audio pipe in Pure Data

Tags: raspberry-pi, airplay, puredata

I'm using shairport-sync, on a Raspberry Pi, and want its audio output to go into Pure Data and then to the speakers (the Pd patch only contains a link between [adc~] and [dac~].

I first tried to select the loopback device as output for shairport and then select it as input in Pure Data but the sound is totally inaudible (whereas when using jackd to do the same, it works well...)

So, following Mike Brady's suggestion I tried to output shairport's audio into a pipe. But I'm stuck then to get the audio into Pd... I can't find any externals or abstraction. Any suggestion on how to handle this ?

Comment: i don't know "Mike Brady's suggestion", but why don't you use jack as backend for shairport, then connect shairport's output to Pd's input, and Pd's output to the system output?

Comment: His suggestion was just about a new feature of shairport-sync, allowing the pipe output, useful for "direct" wiring between apps. The purpose was not to use jack (because I needed a loopback device to wire shairport to jack and then connect jack to Pd. And this wasn't possible on the Rpi, it crashes each time) But you're right I'm gonna try now that I can output directly from shairport to Jack ! 
It's still amazing that nothing can be done from Pd to get the audio from the pipe...
Anyway, Thank you

Comment: actually i find it more amazing that shairport does not support jack and instead invents its own proprietary low-level piping mechanism.